# Why is gdalwarp flipping pixel size sign?

Tags: raster, gdal

I am using the following command:

```
gdalwarp -co COMPRESS=LZW \
    -ts 1024 1024 \
    -cutline cutline.json \
    -crop_to_cutline \
    input.tif \
    output.tif
```

the output raster has the same number of pixels as the input one, but is just cropped to a cutline.

The input raster has pixel size (from gdalinfo):

```
Pixel Size = (159.847049179404479,153.365855104948253)
```

but the output raster has:

```
Pixel Size = (159.820436280028900,-153.866089899794588)
```

Why is gdalwarp flipping the pixel size?

What can I do to have positive size everywhere?

This is with GDAL 2.1.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GDAL, like almost all image libraries, places the origin coordinate for an image in the top-left corner. GDAL just has an extra property of working in a geographic space, and keeps that convention. The first row (*line*) is at the top and successive rows (*lines*) are below it. In a North-up image (*or in a coordinate system with X-right and Y-up and the image aligned to the grid*), this means that successive rows are positioned at successively-less Y-values.

```
Pixel size (x: 5 ; y: -5)
Row 0: Y 20
Row 1: Y 15
Row 2: Y 10
...
```

It is very common to have a negative Y pixel-size, because it allows for a simple calculation of the geographic position of any pixel (*i, j*) in the image.

```
pix_x = origin_x + j * res_x // for example
pix_y = origin_y + i * res_y // for example
```

As to why the image flipped after passing it through `gdalwarp`: The original image you supplied must have placed the geographic origin in the bottom-left corner, effectively mirroring the image across a horizontal axis. The georeferencing used, however, had the data positioned correctly.

Read more about the spatial model, particularly the geotransform in the [GDAL docs](http://gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! And for the formula, applying it manually is working fine for me (`gdal.ApplyGeoTransform` is not for some reason, I will invetigate)